# Ionic Framework: Exporting Project To APK

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created an app in ionic framework. Now i want generate APK of my code by using Android Studio. But i am getting this error

*"Script 'D:\uvionic\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 117
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Unable to determine Android SDK directory."*

will you please help me where i am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

May I ask why you want to export through Android Studio?
[Ionic has a guide on building for Android through Ionic CLI](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html), which might be easier than building manually with Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

add your SDK path in system environment PATH variable (change dir according to your installation)

```
C:/Program Files/android/sdk
```

let me know  if its not working..